# Which houses (are/is) this road connected to?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, subjects, subject-verb-inversion, questions

We are having a debate at my work on if "are" or "is" is the right word to use in the above sentence (actually, a similar sentence which is work-related).

I am aware that there are other ways of rewriting this sentence which avoids this confusion, but keeping the sentence structure in-tact, what is the right word to use here? and why?

> Which houses ____ this road connected to?
>
> 1. are
> 2. is

First time poster here. Be gentle.

Answer (score 2):

You would use **is**. In a *question* like your example sentence, the object is often placed before the subject.  The subject of that sentence is the *road*, and the *houses* are the object of a prepositional phrase (*to which houses*).  You could rephrase the sentence like this:

> This road ___ connected to which houses?

Because "road" is singular, you would say

> This road **is** connected

So your final sentence would be

> Which houses **is** this road connected to?

As an aside, prescriptive grammar perfectionists often admonish "don't end a sentence with a preposition."  One reason is to avoid the sort of confusion that you and your coworker encountered.  [Although this rule is sometimes overkill and often parodied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4XCZfkGF8k), such a grammar ninja would advise writing either

> This road **is** connected to which houses?

or

> To which houses **is** this road connected?

Comment: Isn't the original question asking "Which houses"? In that case wouldn't the answer look more like "Houses 1, 2 and 3 _are_ ..." than "This road is ..." ?

Comment: This road **IS** connected to houses 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @Niyaz you're correct about how **the answer** ***could* look**.  But the most direct answer to that question would be "*This road is connected to houses 1, 2, and 3.*"  Whether you use **is** or **are** is dependent on whether the *subject* of the sentence is singular or plural.  Since "connected" means close to the same thing either way, (A is connected to B ~= B is connected to A), you can choose to use the houses or the road as the subject.  But in the **question** posed in your post, the road is the subject, singular, so you stick with "is."