# Third person singular or plural form of "to be" with plural noun in question

Tags: grammatical-number, be, third-person

A disagreement with a colleague: I say "What measures **are** your company currently implementing?"; she says "what measures **is** your company currently implementing?". It seems obvious to me I am right! Help!

Comment: What is the subject of the sentence?  I say "your company" is the subject.  And "measures" is the direct object of "implement".  The word order is mixed up when it is made into a question.

Comment: Related: [“What questions {is/are} your data team hoping to answer?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80218), [“Which exams is he taking?” or “Which exams are he taking?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460994), [Which houses (are/is) this road connected to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385312/which-houses-are-is-this-road-connected-to?noredirect=1&lq=1), [“What tools is everybody using?” or “What tools are everybody using?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192414)

Comment: The verb in those sentences is *to be implementing*. If the company is the one implementing and the measures are the ones implemented, then the subject of the verb is company, which is singular. If the measures are the ones implementing and the company the one implemented, then the subject is *measures*, which is plural. Both cases are possible. They mean different things. But the measures implementing the company is an unlikely meaning. That is why people are assuming that the subject must be the company.

Comment: If you're both native speakers, try thinking of a similar, but simpler sentence. I bet your grammar sense will kick in.  Is it *What things is he taking?* or *What things are he taking?*

Comment: A number of Q&A on this site deal with the psychological problem of associating singulars and plurals. The psychological problem often wins over the grammatical accuracy, in common use. Here, the problem is overcome by saying 'What measures are you implementing' and leaving the 'you' as unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

> *What measures **are** your company currently implementing?*

If ***are*** sounds better than ***is*** to your ears, I don't think that's necessarily because you're confused as to whether the grammatical subject is *what measures* or *your company*.

This is because you wouldn't think these sound right:

> **What measures **are** it currently implementing?*

OR

> **What measures **are** he currently implementing?*

So for those who find ***are*** sounding better than ***is*** in the original text, the problem arises solely from the question of whether to treat *your company* as singular or plural.

Let's make it a declarative sentence to tease out the treatment of *your company*:

> *Your company **is**/**are** currently implementing these measures.*

If you find ***are*** sounding better here, then your choice of ***are*** in the original text is not a mistake or confusion on your part. It's just that your dialect is that way.

If, however, you find ***is*** better here, then your choice of ***are*** in the original text is a mistake or confusion on your part.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here, both grammatical and psychological that are getting conflated. First, what is the subject? I think most will agree that *company* is the subject but it can be confusing when we use the verb *to be*. After all, there is very little semantic difference between *George is the teacher* and *the teacher is George*. Since *what measures* has been brought to the front (regardless of whether it is the subject or not) then there is room for confusion. The sentence is not far from *What measures are they that your company is/are currently implementing?*. Because this is semantically close it easy for our brains to accept that *measures* is the subject.

Then, even if we accept *company* as the subject there is the question of whether it is singular or plural. Words that represent more than one person (and several beginning with *co-* such as *company*, *council* and *couple*) are often treated as plural even though they are grammatically singular.

However there are some psychological reasons that encourage the use of *are*. One is that *measures are* is, for obvious reasons, far more common than *measures is* and so our brains will tend to favour this form. The other is known as 'attraction', the habit our brains have of making words agree with the nearest one rather then the correct one.

Thus while the 'correct' answer may be *is*, there is a number of reasons, varying in validity, why our brains might choose *are* in this example.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and other answers, according to the grammatical rule of subject-verb agreement, the use of "are" and "is" in a sentence like this should be based on the grammatical number of "your company", because that is the subject of the sentence.

Based on this, it is clear that "is" is acceptable: "company" is singular in form, and therefore can take singular agreement.

Although it not so clear that "are" is wrong, I would advise against using "are".

The only grammatical justification for "are" would be the phenomenon of "notional agreement" (agreement according to the meaning of a word/phrase, as opposed to "formal agreement", which is agreement according to the "form" of a word). But I don't think that plural notional agreement is particularly likely in this case.

1. "Notional agreement" with companies is supposedly uncommon in American English. (See the answers to [Does "staff" take a plural verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/does-staff-take-a-plural-verb)) I'm an American English speaker and this seems a bit of a simplification to me, but nevertheless, it seems to be a commonly repeated guideline. You don't say what variety of English you are using, but since formal agreement is acceptable in all varieties of English, that seems like a safer choice.
2. "Company" does not clearly have a plural meaning in this context. You can think of the company as being composed of multiple people, but the action of "implementing measures" is collective, not distributive. Implementing measures is something that the company does as a whole.
3. As an empirical matter, plural agreement doesn't seem to be common with "company". Here is a relevant [Google Ngram Viewer chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+company+is%2Cthe+company+are%2Cof+the+company+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20company%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20company%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20company%20are%3B%2Cc0):

   [image]

   This is for British English, the variety where notional agreement is supposed to be more common. The chart indicates that the frequency of "the company is" is much greater than the frequency of "the company are", and a substantial portion of the occurrences of "the company are" seem to be in the context "of the company are", where it is probably preceded by a plural noun (e.g. "the employees of the company are" or "the directors of the company are").